# PHP Script Crashes and Max Execution Time

Tags: php, apache

I currently have a website that has twice been suspended by my hosting provider for "overusing system resources". In each case, there were 300 - 400 crashed copies of one of my PHP scripts left running on the server.

The scripts themselves pull and image from a web camera at home and copy it to the server. They make use of file locks to ensure only one can write at a time. The scripts are called every 3 seconds by any client viewing the page.

Initially I was confused, as I had understood that a PHP script either completes (returning the result), or crashes (returning the internal server error page). I am, however, informed that "defunct scripts" are a very common occurrence.

Would anyone be able to educate me? I have Googled this to death but I cannot see how a script can end up in a crashed state. Would it not time out when it reaches the max execution time?

My hosting provider is using PHP set up as CGI on a Linux platform. I believe that I have actually identified the problem with my script in that I did not realise that flock was a blocking function (and I am not using the LOCK_NB mask). I am assuming that somehow hundreds of copies of my script end up blocked waiting for a resource to become available and this leads to a crash? Does this sound plausible? I am reluctant to re-enable the site for fear of it being suspended again.

Any insights greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing why you would need a file lock for this - or, more to the point, why more than one running script would need to write to the same file. It sounds like you might have an ajax call on a `setInterval()` when what you should be doing instead is calling `setTimeout()` in the success handler for the previous ajax call. If you are `flock()`ing a file, make sure you remember to `LOCK_UN` it as soon as you are finished with it, and also remember that if you are reading it you don't need `LOCK_EX`, `LOCK_SH` will suffice.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the provider actually; are they using Apache/suPHP perhaps?

Comment: @Jack I thought that at first, but this could actually be seen with mod_php (just tested it) - because `flock()` blocks and when you're running on *nix the script timeout won't occur if the script never gets to the top of the lock queue. It's pretty silly that this is the case, but apparently it is. There is also a note on the [`set_time_limit()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to that effect.

Comment: @DaveRandom that's true, but eventually _one_ process should eventually stop and release its locks :)

Comment: @Jack But if you are creating new processes faster than they are finishing (which is conceivable when requesting every 3 seconds a script that then goes off and downloads an image from "a web camera at home", which will likely be sitting on a connection with low upload bandwidth) then the queue will keep getting longer and longer. Of course the simple solution to this would be to not lock the destination file until the source file has already been downloaded to a temporary location.

Comment: @DaveRandom thank you for your comments. You are correct in that I am using an Ajax call on SetInterval(). I am requesting LOCK_EX when the file is copied from the camera and written to a temp location on the server. I am requesting LOCK_SH when the file is being read to display.I also had the same thought as you in that surely ONE process must eventually be able to get a lock. My assumption is that, as Jack says, they are being created too quickly.

Comment: @Jack thank you for your comments, I think this is the interpretation of what is happening that I most agree with. I am using LOCK_EX when a script writes the file to a temporary location on the server and LOCK_SH when the script reads it to display. I started using locks as sometimes the file displayed was only half written. I am attempting to ensure that one script finishing writing it before another can read it.

Comment: @Lewis I'm thinking that just converting your `setInterval()` to a `setTimeout()` called in the ajax success handler will solve the problem. This way, request 2 is not initialised until request 1 has completed so you shouldn't get a load of requests all fighting for a lock.

Comment: @DaveRandom thanks Dave, I will give this a try and see if it improves the situation

Answer (score 1):

Probably the approach I would recommend is to use `tempnam()` first and write the contents inside (which may take a while). Once done, you do the file locking, etc.

Not sure if this happens when a PUT request is being done; typically PHP will handle file uploads first before handing over the execution to your script.

Comment: Thanks Jack. Going to re-write my script to give this a try in combination with Dave's suggestion above. Sorry I am a new user and cannot vote up, but appreciated in any event.

Answer (score 0):

Script could crash on these two limitations

- max_execution_time
- memory_limit

while working with resources, unless you have no other errors in script / check for notice errors too